# NSURLConnection Delegate method not being called

Tags: objective-c, macos, ssl, ssl-certificate, nsurlconnection

I'm new to Objective-C and I've been working on some old code trying to dynamically check if SSL-certificate errors should be ignored or not. I have already set a `NSURLConnection` delegate and its methods:

```
@interface Downloader : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate>

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:( NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

Implementation:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
    if([self.ignoreCertificateErrors isEqualToString:@"false"]){
        if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
    _downloadError = error;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_downloadData appendData: data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError * error;
    [_downloadData writeToFile:_downloadDest options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:( NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` is not being called before every download, so the property is not checked and the download happens regardless of the variable's value.

Does anyone know what could cause `NSURLConnection` to ignore its own delegate methods?

(Also, downloads happening asynchronously using `NSRunLoop currentRunLoop`

I know this is kind of an old issue, but non of the other answers have solved this problem for me.

---

This is an extract from the code that performs the asynchronous downloads:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 );
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                      delegate:self
                                                              startImmediately:NO];
        [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [connection start];
        [ [ NSRunLoop currentRunLoop ] run ];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        [connection release];
    });
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Comment: What does Console tell you?  Doesn't `NSURLConnection` require App Transport?  I have not used it for more than 4 years.  So I don't remember how it works.

Comment: Is only this the only delegate method that is not getting called? If none are getting called, that suggests one of any of a number of issues. If only this one is  it getting called, that suggests something different.

Comment: what data type is `ignoreCertificateErrors`?

Comment: Please share how you set the `delegate`. The class that is the delegate should also conform to the delegate protocol: `@interface MyClass:NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate> {...}`

Comment: @Rob Just checked and the other methods are also not being called

Comment: @OlSen NSString

Comment: @ElTomato I'm sure `NSURLSession` does require App Transport, but I'm not sure about `NSURLConnection`

Comment: Did you set breakpoints on each delegate method to be sure they're not getting hit?

Comment: @ManuelRuiz Try using ```NSURLConnectionDataDelegate``` instead. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnectiondatadelegate?language=objc

Comment: By the way, when you declare protocol conformance, you don’t need to repeat the method declarations for the protocol in your header. That’s what the protocol is for.

Answer (score 1):

If a delegate is never called it is very likely that your responsible object does not exist at runtime. In this case a proper made delegate implementation would check if an object to call on exists, is of expected datatype and protocol as well checking if the selector method exists. When all of those are not your issues reason it may be because of missing or wrong parameter/object was given to the delegate objects selector or never called in time.

Often the delegate is just not set after allocation (of class using a delegate) or pointing at the wrong class type or just `NULL` and thats why never processed.

solution:
Check if your `id<DelegateProtocol>` can point to an existing object at runtime and is configured to follow the correct protocol.

reminder:
Implementation of `Classname <ProtocolA, ProtocolB>` helps you code all needed delegate methods and is publishing the method definitions in interface for you. If not - you should see any Xcode warning about it.

hint: in some cases even if documentation says there are defaults you need to set a delegate. And NSURLConnection is deprecated.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. Other than setting `NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:NO];` how else can a delegate be correctly set? or how can I prove that that method is correctly setting it?

Comment: `[connection setDelegate:self];` and check `if (connection.delegate != nil) {..}` or `BOOL nice = [connection.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(YourProtocol)];`

Answer (score 0):

You say that you’re initiating an asynchronous request, but that use of the semaphore is effectively taking an asynchronous API and making it behave synchronously. You should generally avoid using semaphores to make asynchronous methods synchronous unless absolutely necessary. It does not seem appropriate here. You're blocking whatever thread from which you called this. You can conceivably be deadlocking, too.

For what it’s worth, the proper technique of starting `NSURLConnection` on a background thread is complicated. For example, you're calling `CFRunLoopStop` on failure, but not on success. And the use of [`run`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop?language=occ) is explicitly discouraged. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop?language=occ) says:

> If you want the run loop to terminate, you shouldn't use this [`run`] method. Instead, use one of the other run methods and also check other arbitrary conditions of your own, in a loop. A simple example would be:
>
> ```
> BOOL shouldKeepRunning = YES; // global
> NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
> while (shouldKeepRunning && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);
> ```
>
> where `shouldKeepRunning` is set to `NO` somewhere else in the program.

But before worrying about that, we should stop and ask why we are using this background thread at all. It’s much easier to just schedule the `NSURLConnection` on the main run loop. `NSURLConnection` is asynchronous (as long as you avoid using `sendSynchronousRequest`), so there's no need to dispatch the starting of these requests to a background queue. `NSURLConnection` won't block the main thread. (Needless to say, if you're doing any complicated processing in the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods, then you might dispatch that to some GCD queue, but the connection, itself, can just be added to the main runloop without incident.)

If you *really* want to use a background thread for the `NSURLConnection`, don't use semaphores. And use `runMode:beforeDate:` rather than `run`. Or, given that `NSURLConnection` is deprecated anyway, use `NSURLSession`, which can use background thread for its delegate without the runloop silliness.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:` here, not `continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:`.  Otherwise, you're breaking any keychain-based authentication, and probably lots of other stuff.

Also, you need to call `setDelegateQueue:` on the connection before starting the request.  Otherwise, there's some possibility that you might be actively blocking the queue that the callbacks would be sent on.

Finally, you really shouldn't be ignoring certificate errors.  Allowing a specific certificate with a known public key is okay, but ignoring certificate errors en masse is a really bad idea, even for internal builds, because those sorts of bits of code have a tendency to accidentally end up in production.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatching onto the queue and then leaving the block. Once you leave the block connection is released and goes out of scope. Try declaring your connection before the block then wait then release.

```
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                  delegate:self
                                                          startImmediately:NO];

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
     dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 );
     dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
    [ [ NSRunLoop currentRunLoop ] run ];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
});
 dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        [connection release];
```